# Writing a Python 3.9 script to parse a text file and act based on first char of line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and am struggling to figure out how to load a line from a file into a string so I can parse it and act on it.  The input text file is a script for a video that will create Amazon Polly mp3 files, based on the text in the file.

The file uses the first character as either an 'A:'(action, ignore),'F:'(filename),'T:'(text for Polly),or '#' (comment, ignore) then followed by string text, For example:

```
#This example says that the author should move the cursor, then the corresponding Audio
#created from Polly ("Move the cursor to the specified location") is dumped into Move_Cursor.mp3
A:Move the cursor
T:Move the cursor to the specified location
F:Move_Cursor.mp3
#end of example
```

I've been trying to use the read or readline, but I can't figure out how to take the value returned by those to create a string so I can parse it.

```
script_file = open(input("Enter the script filename: "),'r')
lines = script_file.readlines()
cnt = 0

for line in lines:
    eol = len(line)
    print ("line length is: ",eol)
    action = line.read   #<<THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING A TYPE ISSUE
    print ("action is  ",action)
    print ("string is  ",line)
script_file.close()
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: ``line`` already is a string. You don't have (and cannot) to read it anymore – that's what ``readlines()`` already did for you.

Comment: The line `Move_Cursor.mp3` seems to be invalid. Is it supposed to be on the previous line? You can [edit].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this is not really a question. Maybe you want to ask, "How can I separate the first character from a line?" You can [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for more tips. Ideally, you'd provide a [mre] including expected output and actual output (i.e. the full error message with traceback).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```py
filename = input('Enter the script filename: ')

actions = {'#': 'comment', 'A': 'action', 'T': 'text for polly', 'F': 'filename'}

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        lof = len(line)
        action = actions.get(line[0])
        text = line[1:].lstrip(':')

        print(
            f'Length of line: {lof}\n'
            f'        Action: {action}\n'
            f'          Text: {text}\n'
        )
```

Also I would suggest that for choosing files you use the built-in `tkinter` module which has a function for displaying the file chooser (it will limit human error in typing out the correct filename):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

Tk().withdraw()
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Or just skip the filename part:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog

Tk().withdraw()
with filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r') as file:
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Matiis!!!   I will try this out on Monday.  I'm using Kumodo, so it really helps with the variables and syntax, I just was having trouble figuring out what "line" was returning in order to set it into a variable so I could work with it, and I think you did that!  :-)

Comment: Hi Matiis,  Your code got me a little further down the road, but the basic problem that I'm having is that I need to execute code based on the value of the first character of each line in the file.  I'm still banging my head against the wall as to why I keep getting a syntax error trying to check the value of the first character, such as the code below:  
'code'
with script_file:
    for line in script_file:
        action = line[0]
        If action == '#'
               print(f’The string is a comment’)

Comment: @LanetteManzi Well, a syntax error indicates incorrect syntax, for example, incorrect indentation or in the case of what you provided in comments it seems that you need to put a collen after the if statement: `if action == '#':`, notice the `:` at the end there

Comment: Ok, I'm going to just go kill myself now, because I've been beating my head against the wall for two days on this.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @LanetteManzi don't worry, I get your frustration (I too have had times when I can't find the solution or there is some error that is hard to comprehend and internet doesn't help much) but you get some valuable experience out of this which will help you in future to not make the same mistakes or at least you will be able to spot them faster, so good luck with coding and keep on learning!

Answer (score 0):

For those of you interested.  Being new to python, I got sloppy with my spaces and tabs.  My issue with the code, even though it was pointing to a syntax error on a line that should have passed, was that I was mixing spaces and tabs in my indentation, so it lost it's mind.  BUT, THANK YOU for everyone that answered, as it did help me figure out a better way of doing what I was trying to do, and of course, I did find a missing ':' also.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the first character of every line with:

```
action = line[0]
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked - I thought I tried this, but I had tried so many things, I think I just was brain dead at that point, LOL.

Comment: If worked, please consider submitting the question with a tick :)